# ImageResizer not touching file from webapi 2 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, imageresizer

I've read this post:

[ImageResizer is not resizing images served by WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165718/imageresizer-is-not-resizing-images-served-by-webapi)

and I've read the associated FAQ that talks about WebAPI and ImageResizer here:

http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices

I'm still not understanding what I need to do to make files that are served by the route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute
         ("API Vimeo Thumbnail", "rpc/{controller}/{action}/{vimeoId}.jpg",
             new
             {

             });
```

and handled by this controller:

```
public class VimeoController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ActionName("Thumbnail")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Thumbnail(string vimeoId = null, int? width = 1280, int? height = 720)
        {
            string url = String.Format("https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=https%3A//vimeo.com/{0}&width={1}&height={2}", vimeoId, width,
                height);
            var endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
            endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
            endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
            //var endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse) endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            try
            {
                using (WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                        {
                            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                            var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(response));
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                if (reader.Value != null && reader.Value.Equals("thumbnail_url"))
                                {
                                    reader.Read();
                                    string downloadUrl = reader.Value.ToString();
                                    var wc = new WebClient();
                                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(downloadUrl)))
                                    {
                                        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray());
                                        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            responseReader.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

What confuses me is how ImageResizer picks up files in my /Images directory but not from this handler.  Obviously I'm not understanding the pipeline and how to get into it.

Answer (score 0):

ImageResizer does not work this way; it operates prior to the HandleRequest phase in order to take advantage of IIS static file serving. You must subclass BlobProviderBase or implement IVirtualImageProvider if you want to provide custom behavior. If you just need an HTTP request, you might try the RemoteReader plugin (and URL rewriting if you want to change the syntax).

See [integrating with a custom data store](http://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/docs/best-practices#integrating-with-a-custom-data-store) for more information.